# How make bot sent message to every server members

Tags: discord, discord.js

## Discord,js 12.3.1

How I make bot sent message to every members with all servers?

I want to make bot at on_ready

```js
client.on('ready', async (message) => {

});
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! You seem to be asking for someone to write some code for you. Stack Overflow is a question and answer site, not a code-writing service. Please [see here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) to learn how to write effective questions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Depending on how many servers your bot is on and how many users are in that server, your bot will most likely get banned. I do not recommend this in the slightest.

You can use [`GuildMemberManager.fetch()`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/GuildMemberManager?scrollTo=fetch), which will fetch all members in a server, partnered with a few [`for... of`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...of) loops.

```js
// const client = new Discord.Client();

client.on('ready', async () => {
 for (const guild of client.guilds.cache)
  for (const user of await guild.members.fetch())
   user.send('message').catch(() => console.log('User had DMs disabled'));
});
```

One problem with this method is that some users may be DMd multiple times if they're in multiple of these servers (aside from the obvious problems being it takes up a huge amount of memory, and your bot will probably get banned)

You could also enable enable the [`fetchAllMembers`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/typedef/ClientOptions) option when initializing the client.

> Whether to cache all guild members and users upon startup, as well as upon joining a guild (should be avoided whenever possible)

Again, as the description says, this should be avoided whenever possible (I'm only showing it to be thorough).

```js
// const client = new Discord.Client({ fetchAllMembers: true });

client.on('ready', () => {
 for (const user of client.users.cache)
  user.send('message').catch(() => console.log('User had DMs disabled'));
});
```

---

I cannot stress enough how bad of an idea this is.